# Get entity by email in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to get the user from his email , the email is unique in the database.

I write this code :

```
session.beginTransaction();
User user =  (User) session.createQuery("select * from `user`  where email = '"+email+"'");
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Is this code right ? or there is some function in hibernate to get entity by column value ?

Comment: Create query should be what you're looking for, except if the email is the ID, then you could just use `get`. But note that you should not simply put the email in the string for security reasons. You should use parameters, like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340346/prepared-statements-hibernate-and-hql

Comment: No, it isn't right. createQuery expects a JPQL query. And what you passed is not JPQL. Learn JPQL: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql. Also learn to use query parameters instead of concatenation, because your code is vulnerable to SQL/JPQL injection attacks. Finally, as documented, createQuery returns a Query, not a User. You need to **execute** that query, using getResultList() or getSingleResult().

Comment: Indeed I didn't notice how exactly the query was written, but `createQuery` is still the method to use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems with your current code.  First, you appear to be running a native SQL query, not HQL (or JPQL).  Second, your query is built using string concatenation, leaving it prone to attack by SQL injection

Consider the following code:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User u where u.email = :email ");
query.setParameter("email", email);
List list = query.list();
```

Comment: Transactions are not just used for atomicity. Isolation is also important. And being able to navigate to the graph of entities after the query has returned is also important. A transaction is always a good idea. Also, it should be `select u from User u...` with a capital U, since that's the class name.

Comment: @JBNizet When I wrote that I was thinking JDBC, in which case we probably wouldn't use an explicit transaction for a simple select, but rather for updates etc. where we would want the option to do a rollback.  Yes, every hit of the DB in Hibernate probably has a transaction behind it.  The OP left out this code (and a bunch of other things).

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but It seem that using "Query " class is deprecated in hibernate

Comment: Thank you again @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Without writting any SQL:

```
  public static Person getPersonByEmail(String email)  {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<Person> cr = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
        Root<Person> root = cr.from(Person.class);
        cr.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get("email"), email));  //here you pass a class field, not a table column (in this example they are called the same)

        Query<Person> query = session.createQuery(cr);
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        List<Person> result = query.getResultList();
        session.close();

        return result.get(0);
  }
```

**example of use:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
  Person person = getPersonByEmail("test@mail.com");
  System.out.println(person.getEmail());  //test@mail.com
}
```